# Powershell regex replace specific case/characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use powershell and regex to take the text of a csv and format the lines in a specific way.  I need to take the A-TO-B section of the path and convert it to A-to-B, now I can achieve this if its only A-TO-B by using

```
-replace "\b[a-z]-TO-[a-z]\b","A-to-B"
```

however there are other groupings I need to deal with c-to-d for example.

```
-replace "\b[a-z]-TO-[a-z]\b","\U[a-z]\b-to-\b\U[a-z]"
```

the above code obviously doesn't work but it was my attempt at trying to wrap my head around what I want to do.

```
P:\CLIENTS\A-TO-B\

P:\CLIENTS\A-TO-B\

P:\CLIENTS\c-TO-d\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a positive lookbehind and lookahead to find the position of the `TO` and replace it with `to`:

```
(?<=\w-)TO(?=-\w)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/aB5zM1/1)

**PowerShell:**

```
-replace '(?<=\w-)TO(?=-\w)',"to"
```